# How do I get data from public interface to use?

Tags: c#

There is a public interface in the project with a value as follows:

```
Name3D MyName3D { get; set; }
```

Now in another location I am using a public sealed class, I added the namespace / using System.Interfacename. Now I want to set it like follows:

```
private readonly Interfacename m_MyName3D ;
private const string 3DName = ##;
```

How would i go aobut setting it up so ## is the value of MyName3D. Again I haven't done anything like this before. Just wanted to give it a try?

Would be really appreciated if I could get some detail onto how it works.

**Update One**

Do you mean this?

```
using Interfacename;

public sealed class InfoController : AsyncController
{
    private readonly Interfacename m_MyName3D ;
    private const string 3DName = ##;
```

Comment: Could you post your class as well? Basically if your class implements the interface, then you have MyName3D in your class, and can just assign to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not assign anything to a const member at runtime. You can however make 3DName a readonly property and relay the get accessor to the interface:

```
private string 3DName { get { return m_MyName3D.MyName3D; } }
```

But maybe I did not get what you are trying to do, if so please describe it more clearly.

edit: you are using two types for 3DName, Name3D and string. If Name3D has no conversion operators you need to use it throughout the property.

```
private Name3D 3DName { get { return m_MyName3D.MyName3D; } }
```

If you really need to return a string the you need to write a string conversion operator for Name3D:

```
struct/class Name3D
{
  public static implicit operator string(Name3D name)
  {
      return name.whatever; // this needs to be the data holding member(s) of Name3D
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I would describe more clearly if I knew what I was trying to do xD

Comment: "cannot impliclty convert Name3D  to string" I would say you got exactly what I want to do because I want be able to use "3DName" as part of a URI so I need the value of it